# How to change the format of a Date within gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, format

[image]

I'd like to change the date column in my gridview so that it is DD-MM-YYYY and then a space for Time at the end in  the format of 00:00:00

The name of the column is thedate and the column number is 2
I've tried `dataGridView1[2]["thedate"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

```
 String str = dataGridView1[2]["thedate"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
       String formated = dataGridView1.Columns[2].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");


String formated = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", dataGridView1.Columns[2]);
```

and none of them work i'm not sure where to go from here! thanks

Comment: try do that in CellFormatting event ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
 dataGridView1[2]["thedate"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

This code is not a Datetime instance.

First convert `dataGridView1[2]["thedate"]` to `DateTime` then use `ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");`

on it. That would work.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply darth :) i'll look up how to do that now thanks again!

Comment: haha only if I can get this working :p looking up how to use datetime nowwww

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = Datatime.TryParse(dataGridView[2]["thedate"].ToString());
String dtFormat = dt.Tostring("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Should Help.

Comment: thanks alot for the reply malcor :) the bottom line seems to be working however the top line has a couple of errors, method used like a type and no overload method :/ http://gyazo.com/85b59af8d0eeb316a834e99d652ba2c7.png

Comment: Lose the Try from the TryParse

Comment: There I have fixed it. You can initialise a new instance of DT before trying to parse, or you can drop the 'new keyword from the previous version and insitalise it with the data straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```